# Waiting for multiple asynchronous download tasks

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I want to download some files, for example 100 files, at the same time. So I decided to add my download threads to a dispatch queue, and GCD will adjust how many threads will run at the same time.

The problem here is: the block in `dispatch_async` will be completed immediately, because `task` will run on another thread. So, if `urls`'s length is 100, it will create 100 threads immediately.

```
var queueDownloadTask = dispatch_queue_create("downloadQueue", nil)

for url in urls {
    dispatch_async(queueDownloadTask) {

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let fileTransferSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = fileTransferSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (responseUrl, response, error) -> Void in
            println("completed")
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

**How can I configure the block in `dispatch_async` to wait for the download task to complete?** I don't want use `dispatch_semaphore`, because it only allow run one download task at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for multiple blocks to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985015/waiting-for-multiple-blocks-to-finish)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To expand on Abhinav's answer, you should:

1. Use `dispatch_group_create()` to create a group.
2. Call `dispatch_group_enter(group)` before starting each download task.
3. Call `dispatch_group_leave(group)` inside the task's completion handler.
4. Then call `dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{ ... })` to enqueue a block that will be executed when all the tasks are completed.

You can see an example in [this post](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/).

(By the way, it's not true that doing 100 `dispatch_async`s in a row will create 100 threads immediately. The system still retains control over how many threads to use to satisfy the queue. However, your code does not wait for any of the tasks to complete before it returns, nor does it attempt to synchronize between multiple tasks completing.)

Comment: I think this is a valid answer. Additionally, using a separate queue to schedule tasks (like the `queueDownloadTask`) is unnecessary as `task.resume()` returns immediately. Just using the main queue to schedule them is good enough.

Comment: True. I would recommend that as well.

Answer (score 48):

In Swift 4,

```
func executeMultiTask() {
     //1. Create group
     let taskGroup = DispatchGroup()

     //2. Enter group
     taskGroup.enter()
     myTask1.execute(completeHandler: {
         // ...
         //3. Leave group
         taskGroup.leave() //< balance with taskGroup.enter()
     })

     /* Add more tasks ...
     //2. Enter group
     taskGroup.enter()
     myTask2.execute(completeHandler: {
         //3. Leave group
         defer {
            // Use `defer` to make sure, `leave()` calls are balanced with `enter()`.
            taskGroup.leave() 
         }
         // ... more
     })
     */

     //4. Notify when all task completed at main thread queue.
     taskGroup.notify(queue: .main) { 
         // All tasks are done.
         // ...   
     }

}
```

Comment: Just curious, how can `defer` help balance `leave()` and `enter()` calls? Wouldn't it also be balanced without `defer`?

Comment: @Hlung, `defer` is `Swift` syntax. It will be executed finally. [I google a document](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-defer). It's like `try/finally`.

Comment: `defer` is nice if you have multiple exit conditions in a scope. But if you don't, I think `defer` is not needed. We can just put `taskGroup.leave()` at the end of the scope.

Comment: I think it is a habit problem. When I write `taskGroup.enter()`, I put a `taskGroup.leave()` at next 2 ~ 3 lines. If the sub-routine is 20 ~ 30 lines long, it's hard to trace that the `enter()`, and `leave()` are balanced.

Comment: This doesn't work 100% of times in iOS 11 for some reason. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 5):

A working objective-c example for downloading multi files

```
- (void) downloadFiles: (NSMutableArray *) fileArray : (NSString *)destParentDir{
    dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    for (id fileInfo in fileArray) {
        dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *fileName = [fileInfo valueForKey:@"name"];

        //Create SubDirs if needed, note that you need to exclude file name for the dirsString :)
        //[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dirsString withIntermediateDirectories:true attributes:nil error:NULL];

        //Download file
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_FILE_URL"];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if(urlData)
        {
            NSString  *localPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", destParentDir, fileName];
            [urlData writeToFile:localPath atomically:YES];
        }
        dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        NSLog(@"Complete files download");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `dispatch_group_t`. Please refer to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) to solutionize your case.

Comment: I don't know how to apply dispatch_group to this situation :(

Comment: "solutionize"! Great!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DispatchGroup`. Wrap each download in `enter` and `leave`. Provide a callback to `notify`, which will be called when all pairings have completed.

```swift
var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for url in urls {
    // ... Set up the download
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    let task = fileTransferSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url) { (responseUrl, response, error) -> Void in
        println("Individual download complete.")
        dispatchGroup.leave()
     })
    task.resume()

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        println("All downloads complete.")
    }
}
```